Why NRSVUE render different translations from the same word "satan"?
In Hebrew, the word satan is not a name, so as in english, we're allowed to add the definite article before it in hebrew as well.
From wikipedia:

When used without the definite article (simply satan), it can refer to any accuser,[10] but when it is used with the definite article (ha-satan), it usually refers specifically to the heavenly accuser, literally, the satan.

Let's take a look at 1 chronicles 21:1 and 1 kings 5:4 with NRSVUE translations.  Even though, in both of hebrew, there's no article added to the word, NRSVUE translations still end up different. in 1 chronicles 21:1, translation is directly "satan" where as in 1 kings 5:4, trasnlation is adversary.
Can anyone explain why it is that even though none of them have articles, the translation is still different ?

This question is similar to: Why the name Satan was mention only in 3 books of the Old Testament?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please consider other answers having already been given to address your question or edit your question to be more specific and unique to your core research.

I think the simplest answer is that the 1 Chronicles translation is perhaps theologically motivated, whereas the 1 Kings translation is more directly grammatical. The 1 Chronicles translation may also be seeking to account for the alternative description of the same event in 1 Samuel 24:1, which says that it was the Lord who incited David against Israel. So the "Satan" translation may be out of a desire to consider the potential reality of either spiritual warfare or divine judgment, perhaps even a sovereign judgment of God where Satan is involved.
It's also worth noting that the NRSVUE is far from the only translation to have these differences: the KJV, ESV, NIV, NLT, NASB, and many others have the same readings in both places. The NET is one of the only modern ones to render "an adversary" in the 1 Chronicles text. Here's their defense:

"The Hebrew word שָׂטָן (satan) refers to an adversary, typically used
without the article to refer to anyone in an adversarial role. Used
with the article in Job 1-2 and Zech 3:1-2, it refers to “The Satan,”
the demonic opponent. Of the heavenly accuser in those passages
NIDOTTE (IV, 1231) says that “it is improbable that a specific demonic
being is referred to (a possible exception may be 1 Chr 21:1).” TLOT
(p. 1269) believes that 1 Chr 21:1 represents the first use of “satan”
without the article as a personal name."

That last line is the crucial point, which I think is part of the challenge you are seeing. If the correct translation for the 1 Chronicles passage is indeed "Satan," then it would be the only time in the OT that it is used without the article. The NET explanation continues in a second note at the end of the verse:

"The parallel text in 2 Sam 24:1 says, “The Lord’s anger again raged
against Israel and he incited David against them, saying: ‘Go, count
Israel and Judah!’” The version of the incident in the Book of 2
Samuel gives an underlying theological perspective, while the
Chronicler simply describes what happened from a human perspective.
Many interpreters and translations render the Hebrew שָׂטָן as a
proper name here, “Satan” (NEB, NASB, NIV, NRSV). However, the Hebrew
term שָׂטָן, which means “adversary,” is used here without the
article. Elsewhere when it appears without the article, it refers to a
personal or national adversary in the human sphere, the lone exception
being Num 22:22, 32, where the angel of the Lord assumes the role of
an adversary to Balaam. When referring elsewhere to the spiritual
entity known in the NT as Satan, the noun has the article and is used
as a title, “the Adversary” (see Job 1:6-9, 12; 2:1-4, 6-7; Zech
3:1-2). In light of usage elsewhere the adversary in 1 Chr 21:1 is
likely a human enemy, probably a nearby nation whose hostility against
Israel pressured David into numbering the people so he could assess
his military strength."


+1. Good answer.
